# Pdf and Cdf of a triangle

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

A probability distribution is described by a triangle which has
minimum value $x=a$, modal value $x=b$ and maximum $x=c$. Sketch the pdf and cdf for this
distribution. Write down the functional form of the pdf and cdf.

The pdf sketch is easy enough I think I got that but the rest is giving me trouble. I know what a pdf and cdf are but having trouble visualizing a cdf and in turns turning the diagrams into an equation.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution) has pictures of an example pdf (triangular) and cdf (two parabolic arcs, one upward and one downward, stuck together)

Comment: @Henry I'll have a look Thanks.

Comment: @Henry do you know if it's possible to see the thought process behind how they derived the pdf and cdf equations?

Comment: @P123 the pdf comes from your original definition (though Wikipedia has swapped $b$ and $c$), constrained to have an area of $1$.  The cdf is just the integral of the pdf